# How to retrieve data with AsyncStorage multiGet in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm considering how to use React-native AsyncStorage multiGet in docs written:

```
AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
```

But how those keys should properly look like? Here is how they are set within my application:

```
AsyncStorage.multiSet([['@BarcodeList', JSON.stringify(scanedList)], ['@ScannedBarcode', gotCode]]);
```

It's ok, but how can i retrieve that data with multiGet? With getItem it seems working, what i am doing wrong? both(getItem, multiGet) of them below.

```
AsyncStorage.multiGet(["@BarcodeList", "@ScannedBarcode"]).then((scanedList2, scannedBarcode) => {
    //AsyncStorage.getItem("@BarcodeList").then((scanedList2) => {
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It works the following way, since it gives *nested array response*

The array contains **key** as `index 0` and **value** as `index 1`

```
 AsyncStorage.multiGet(["@BarcodeList", "@ScannedBarcode"]).then(response => {
            console.log(response[0][0]) // Key1
            console.log(response[0][1]) // Value1
            console.log(response[1][0]) // Key2
            console.log(response[1][1]) // Value2
        })
```