# Not able to use map function react-native

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, state, setstate

I am new to react native and I am using Async storage to store objects and then parse, by storing them in favorites array. I am trying to map each element in array and display it.

I get this error: this.state.favorites.map is not a function.
I think it's a state error but as I'm new to these concepts, i don't know how to fix it. Please help.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image,  FlatList, Button, AsyncStorage, 
TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import ajax from './ajax.js';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import InspirationList from './InspirationList';
import FavoriteItem from './FavoriteItem';
import ProductItem from './ProductItem';


class Favorites extends Component{
    state = {
        favorites:[],
      };

componentDidMount(){
    this.showProduct();
  }

    async showProduct() {
        let k=0;
        AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
            .then(keys => AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
            .then((result) => {
                result.map(req => req.forEach((element) => {
                    k++;
                    if(element!=null && k%2==0){
                    this.setState({favorites: JSON.parse(element) });
                    console.log(this.state.favorites.nume);
                     }
                  }));       
            }));
        };

  render(){
    return(
    <View style='styles.fav'>
        {this.state.favorites.map((fav)=>
            <Text>{fav.nume}</Text>
        )}
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
 fav:{
     backgroundColor:'#999',
     flex:1,
     width:'100%',
     paddingTop:150,
 }
});

export default Favorites;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `showProduct` function you are overriding what your state originally was. When assigning the `JSON.parse(element)` you are changing your state instead of having an array your are converting it into an object, that's why you are getting that error. `map` exists only on array-like.

So maybe you can do something like:

```
async showProduct() {
        let k=0;
        AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
            .then(keys => AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
            .then((result) => {
                result.map(req => {
                  let result = [];
                  req.forEach((element) => {
                    k++;                        
                    if(element!=null && k%2==0){
                      result.push(JSON.parse(element))
                    }
                    });
                  this.setState({favorites: result });}
              );       
            }));
        };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Apparently, the syntax that you provided is incorrect. I get a syntax error on let result=[]. I tried to move the let declaration on top, where let k=0 is. If I do that, I get an array that has twice the objects. The first half contains strings of objects and the other half the objects.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I fix this? I want to avoid duplicates because I get an error of 'duplicate keys. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I did not double check, problem was missing open and closing curly braces for callback pass to `map` function. I edit again answer, can you try with the actual code?

Comment: And also you can check [react-native multiget doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#multiget) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133440/how-to-retrieve-data-with-asyncstorage-multiget-in-react-native) question from someone who is asking how to manage response from `multiget()`.

Comment: No problem, it also helps me too. Glad I could help you. :)