# How to get multi keys from AsyncStorage and then add these keys into an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I wanna get multi keys from AsyncStorage and add these keys into an array.

```
AsyncStorage.multiGet(
 ['key1',
  'key2',
  'key3',
  'key4',
  'key5',]
).then(() => {

})
```

Comment: [`multiGet`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#multiget) takes a callback function as second argument, and this callback function is called with the array `[['key1', 'dataForKey1'], ['key2', 'dataForKey2'], ...  ]`

Comment: I am sorry but I am junior engineer so if you can, could you give me an example ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133440/how-to-retrieve-data-with-asyncstorage-multiget-in-react-native This is a repeat question. It gives you an array back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve data with AsyncStorage multiGet in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50133440/how-to-retrieve-data-with-asyncstorage-multiget-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map function for this:

```
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
  AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
    stores.map((result, i, store) => {
      // get at each store's key/value so you can work with it
      let key = store[i][0];
      let value = store[i][1];
    });
  });
});
```

this is an example from doc here [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#multiget)

Answer (score 0):

```js
async getKeysData(keys){
  const stores = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
  return stores.map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))
}

getKeysData(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
 .then((response)=>{ console.log(response)})
 
 /*
 Respose will be in below form 
 response = [
  {key1: 'DATAOF key1'},
  {key2: {"DATA OF KEY2"}}
  {key3: 'DATAOF key1'}
*/
```