# Get all Async storage data keys and set them as states

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for a way to retrieve in one time all AsyncStorage keys / values and set them as states in React Native.

For example :

```
const asyncOne = async name => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('nameOne', 'saad');
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('nameTwo', 'otherName');
    // a lot more 
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error);
  }
};
```

What I would like to do is to set all of them automatically as states in componentDidMount() and get something like this :

```
state = {
nameOne : saad,
nameTwo : otherName,
// All others
};
```

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all keys and values from AsyncStorage by using `getAllKeys()` and `multiGet()` function.

After get json repsonse, set it to state with `setState()` function.

Here is example(FYI, I didn't test it)

```
readAsyncData = async () => {  
  try {  
     const keys =await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();  
     const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);  
     // do something what you need with response
     this.setState({
       data: result
     });
  } catch (error) {
     // do something...
  }
}
```

To get the state.

```
const {data} = this.state;  
let firstname = data.firstname;
```

PS. you can get more details about [muitlGet()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50133841) function